# How to user javascript with asp.net viewstate

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have UL in my page, and it is empty.
I start populating it with LI using javascript.

How can I use this newly added dynamic data in the asp.net in the postback phase?

that is  because my submit button is asp.net control.
I do not want to use JS POST.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this sort of thing in the past by populating a hidden field with the dynamic data to be posted back, you could either -

- Fire a JavaScript event before postback that parsed the data out of the UL into a hidden field

or

- Update the hidden field as you update the contents of the UL

Answer (score 1):

LI is not transferred over POST. Only elements of form: INPUT (text, hidden...), OPTIONS, are passed.
So the simplest way is create hidden field
`<input type='hidden' name='myData' id='myData' ...`

and at ASP.net side access just created control by

```
HttpRequest request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
String value = request.Form["myData"]
```